# R: adding a plot legend in R

Tags: r, plot, visualization

```
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width, col = iris$Species)
```

[image]

I know that I can use the `legend()` function to manually set my legend. However, I have no idea which color was assigned to the different species in my data? Is there an automatic way to get `plot()` to add a legend?

Comment: the default colors will be `palette()[as.integer(iris$Species)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @rawr says, `palette()` determines the colour sequence used. If you use integers to specify colours, it will also look at `palette()`. Thus

```
with(iris,plot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, col = Species))
legend("topright",legend=levels(iris$Species),col=1:3, pch=1)
```

works nicely.

[image]

Base R doesn't have an auto-legend facility: the `ggplot2` package does.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,colour=Species))+geom_point()
```

gives you a plot with an automatic legend (use `theme_set(theme_bw())` if you don't like the grey background).

[image]

The built-in `lattice` package can also do automatic legends:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(Sepal.Width~Sepal.Length,group=Species,data=iris,auto.key=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: probably it would be nice to add some sample images.